# Javascript: Run a function defined outside this closure as if it were defined inside this closure

Tags: javascript

I want to have a function A that accepts another function B as an argument, and then runs B as it were defined within the closure scope of A, i.e. has access to all the local variables.

For example, simplistically:

```
var A = function(B){
  var localC = "hi";
  B();
}

var B = function(){
  console.log(localC);
}

A(B); // to log 'hi'
```

The only way I have found is to use eval. Does ec6 give any better options maybe?

Comment: Functions keep their original scope permanently and can't adopt new ones. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Can't you put both of them in a new closure? Take a search for "self executing functions for javascript", it's a method of creating a common closure without having to define new functions.

Comment: Closures (situations where the compiler maintains a variable reference in a different function) only work when a function is actually contained inside another function. (So, two function openers, then two close braces, in that order). Pretty sure this isn't possible. I could help further if you detail your reasons for wanting this.

Comment: I'm developing a library that provides a load of utility functions for drawing to canvas. The idea is you can create scripts that combine the different functions together. Currently the utilities are all available on an object and you need to call them as methods of that object: o.circle() o.square() etc. It would be neater if you could leave of the 'o.' That is all! I could assign all the functions to global scope, but I'd rather not do that. I'd rather define the functions in a closure, and be able to pass in a function that can then use them there.

Comment: If there's a single, shared `o` object, you can `.bind()` the `o` to the functions, but that really has nothing to do with variable scope. Why not provide an example that truly illustrates what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the context explicit and pass it to `B`:

```
var A = function(B){
    var context = {
        localC: "hi"
    };
    B(context);
}

var B = function(context){
    console.log(context.localC);
}

A(B); // hi
```

---

You can also use `this` with `new` and `prototype`:

```
var A = function() {
    this.localC = "hi";
}
A.prototype.b = function(context){
    console.log(this.localC);
}

var a = new A();
a.b(); // hi
```

---

or without the `prototype`:

```
var A = function() {
    this.localC = "hi";
}

var a = new A();
a.b = function(context){
    console.log(this.localC);
};
a.b(); // hi
```

---

You can use `this` with `bind`:

```
var a = {
    localC: "hi"
};
function B(foo) {
    console.log(this.localC, foo);
}
B.bind(a)("foo"); // hi foo
// .call:
B.call(a, "foo"); // hi foo
```

`bind` sets the context for `this`. `call` takes the context as it's first argument.

---

This one is **not** good:

```
var A = function(B){
    var localC = "hi";
    B.bind(this)(); // this is the global object, you need `new` to create a new scope
}

var B = function(){
    console.log(this.localC);
}
A(B); // undefined
```

Comment: the problem with all these methods is that you need to preface the variables you want to access with the object that contains them. See my comment to reply 1. All I'm actually trying to do is simplify the use of the variables so you don't need to preface them with this.x or o.x or self.x, which clutters the code in my use case. I realise this is probably impossible though

Comment: @gostone: You can use the `with` statement, though it's generally discouraged and has been removed in "strict mode". But again, I don't know what `o.x` syntax has to do with variables. If that's all you need, then `.bind()` the `o` object to the `x` method.

Comment: Genius! `with` is what I'm looking for! I didn't think that was possible. Thanks a lot! Shame it is not compatible with strict mode, and I can see why, but actually it might fit my use case quite well. Thanks everyone for your help. I'll mark the question as answered.

Comment: There is a reason `with` is not in strict mode, it's considered a _bad_ feature. Don't use it. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: Like you, I have always understood it to be a 'bad' feature, which is why I have never used it in the past, and it didn't spring to mind this time. But in this case there are two counter-arguments. Firstly, none of the "contra"s in that article apply to this use case. Secondly, I will not be using it in my library, only in scripts written with my library, and even then it is an optional pattern to reduce clutter in the script. The user of the library can choose.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to pass `localC` as argument in function `B`:

```js
var A = function(B) {
  var localC = "hi";
  B(localC);
}

var B = function(localC) {
  console.log(localC);
}

A(B); // outputs hi
```

Alternative using `arguments`:

```js
var A = function(B) {
   var localC = "hi";
   B(localC, "test");
 }

 var B = function() {
   var i = 0;
   for (i; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     console.log(arguments[i]);
   }
 }

 A(B); // outputs hi, test
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It doesn't do what the OP describes.

Comment: hmmm @squint why it doesn't? OP wants to access local variables.

Comment: Because it's not accessing the variable. It's copying it to a new variable (parameter) and it relies on the function `B` defining such a parameter.  What you've given is a possible alternative that may or may not work for the OP's actual situation, but it's not a solution to the given problem, since there is no solution in JS.

Comment: I provide alternative using `arguments`

Comment: In a generic setting, these work. Ultimately you're making `B` conform to `A` in a way not described in the question. Again, it may be a useful alternative, but it's not really doing what the OP describes. If we did this, then we might as well just define `localC` globally or at least in an IIFE shared by both.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var A = function(B){
  var self = this;
  self.localC = "hi";
  self.localD = "hello";
  B();
};

var B = function(){
  var self=this;
  alert(self.localD);
}

A(B); // to log 'hi'
```

Comment: `this` is actually `window`, so it's cheating a bit.

Comment: thanks! Neat trick! I was able to do something like this myself. It doesn't answer my needs though. See my comment to question 1. Halcyon is right actually. My trick involved newing up a class.